# In Windows 10 is there a way to send text selected in an application to Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I would like to be able to select text in a text editing application and then send that selection directly to PowerShell for further processing and manipulation.  I realize that I can select and copy with the mouse, then get the text from the clipboard, but I would like to cut out the clipboard step if possible.

My use case is a workflow where I have to make a lot of individual text selections from a set of files (the selections I need vary on a case by case basis, and cannot be done programmatically).  I would like to set up a simple keyboard shortcut to automatically get the selected text and append it to a preset text file.

I do it this way on OSX, so I just wanted to see if it is possible in Windows before I start trying to script using the clipboard.

EDIT:

@SimonMᶜKenzie: I'm using Sublime Text 3 primarily, but I actually interact with my files from different editors sometimes (Visual Studio Code, some markdown previewers, etc.).  On OSX, I even used the "get-selected-text" capability to grab stuff out of web browsers, and so on, and it was kind of nice not to have to create macros for each of the editors I use.  It was pretty handy to have a single "get-text-anywhere" capability everywhere.

I'm switching from Mac to Windows, and everything is quite different.  I've committed to try learn stuff a Windowsy way, rather than try to force Win to be Unix/OSX. I'm kind of just testing things out right now to see what capabilities might be available in Windows.  If it is not there, I'm happy to make due, but I wanted to make sure first, before I invest time in some of the other options.

Comment: What text editor are you using? I'm sure many editors will have built-in macro languages for these sorts of tasks.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I use a couple of different editors, and having the capability in a single place is just a convenience I got used to using.  I've edited my question to help give a little more context to what I'm looking for.

Comment: AFAIK detecting and accessing selected text are unique for each application, so you would need to create a macro in the application (if it supports it) and have it ex. trigger the common powershell-script to process the data. I would probably go for the clipboard solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only tried this on Windows 10, so it might differ for older versions:

```
While ($true) {
    if ([System.Windows.Clipboard]::ContainsText()) {
        $Var = [System.Windows.Clipboard]::GetText("Text")
        [System.Windows.Clipboard]::Clear()
        <do stuff>
    }
    else {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5
    }
}
```

It's not a dedicated shortcut, but it will grab any text you copy into your clipboard...
You should also be able to get the exact behaviour you want using the .net classes such as System.Windows.Input.Keyboard, but that is probably a lot more effort.

Comment: Inventive, but it breaks normal copy-paste. Perhaps you need to keep track of the previous clipboard value instead of clearing the clipboard...

Comment: Yes, it breaks copy paste. It sounds to me like the script would only be run if that specific Task that involves marking the text is being performed, so it doesn't seem like a big issue to me. If one wanted to save the content of the clipboard, one would have to define a new key combination (which probably is possible using System.Windows.Input.Keyboard) and then copy the text to clipboard and press that combination. Which sounds rather unwieldy imho.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm going to play around with it and see what happens.  My Powershell/VB/.net chops are pitiful right now, so I'lI use this to practice and see if I can make it work. It seems pretty close to what I want, so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, since I get the sense that the overall best answer with regard exactly what I want is "It's probably not worth the effort".  I've found AutoHotKey, so I'm going to see if I can work that into something also.